# How to introduce loop structure to compare different values with same key in a table?

Tags: loops, netlogo

in my model on opinon exchange I created one table that stores initial-opinions of each turtle for all patch-clusters in the model. The tabel involves cluster- id as key and opinion as value. The result is as wanted.

```
     ask myself [ table:put dict_Opinion cluster-id opinion ]
     ask myself [show dict_Opinion]
```

In the next step I link two random-turtles to each other.

```
 repeat (count turtles / 2)                             
   [let resident turtles with [not any? link-neighbors] 
   let res1 one-of resident
   let res2 one-of other resident  

   ;;create link --> check that turtle1 is not turtle2
   if res1 != res2  
   [ask res1 [create-link-with res2 [ set color 55]
```

Now they should calculate differences in opinions  on a certain cluster-id and check it against a social distance threshold. Something like that....

```
   ;; calculate social distance   
   let soc-dist ( (abs[ opinion ] of res1 - [ opinion ] of res2))
   ;; Check if social distance is below a certain social-distance threshold
   if (soc-dist < Social_Distance_Threshold)
```

What I thought about was introducing a loop structure, that calculates the difference in opinions and checks it against the threshold. If differences in opinions are below the threshold the following formula should be run...

```
   [ask res1
   [set opinion (opinion + ( mu * ([opinion ] of res2 - opinion )))
    if ([opinion ] of res1 > 1) [ask res1 [set opinion 1] ]
    if ([opinion ] of res1 < 0) [ask res1 [set opinion 0] ]

   ask res2
  [set opinion (opinion + mu * (((([opinion ] of res1 - (mu *     opinion )) /   ( 1 - mu)) - opinion ))) 
   if ([opinion ] of res2 > 1) [ask res2 [set opinion 1]]
   if ([opinion ] of res2 < 0) [ask res2 [set opinion 0]]
```

However, after trying and searching for quite some time, it is difficult to introduce a loop structure  that implements subsequent steps after turtles were linked together. I do not understand how to compare the different values for the same cluster-id with a loop in Netlogo.

I would be very pleased for any hints and suggestions.
Thank you very much!

Jan

Comment: I am very unclear what you mean by 'loop' in this context. It looks like you are just asking res1 and res2 to each change their opinion once. Why is this not `if soc-dist < Social_Distance_Threshold [commands you want done]`?

Comment: "Now they should calculate differences in opinions on a certain cluster-id and check it against a social distance threshold"   Sorry, this was confusing. Actually, linked turtles shall calculate per tick all differences in opinions by comparing all opinions that are stored in the same table. In the next tick, res1 randomly links to another res2 and the same approach starts again...

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by 'it is difficult to introduce a loop structure that implements subsequent steps after turtles were linked together'. Whether there is a link or not has no effect on being able to ask res1 and res2 to access a table. Or is the problem that you don't know how to get the full set of table <key, value> pairs to compare to?

Comment: Indeed, that is my problem. The link is working fine but I  do not understand how to compare the full set of the table...

Comment: so res1 and res2 are both individuals and they each have a cluster-id and that cluster-id is the key to an opinion value. Is that correct? And then, for each of res1 and res2 you want to compare its opinion to all the opinions of all the cluster-ids. But you only refer to those nodes in the current code. I think you want `table:keys` to get the keys as a list, then do a foreach through that list and for each item in the list (that is, each cluster-id), get the value with `table:get dict_Opinion ?` to get the opinion. I have no idea if this will work.

Comment: I am not clear why you want the table since you are looping through the lot. You might consider cluster as a breed, and each cluster has an attribute for members, and the value of that attribute is a list of the agents in that cluster. Then you can easily loop by `ask [members] of cluster` or similar.